# Magento 2.3. Need to grant access to customer for using some APIs

Tags: magento2.3

I have gone through from regular authentication process as a customer and successfully used some Magento Rest APIs. Some APIs are working fine and some apis are returning responses like that;

Example: I need to get details of a specific product:

```
Endpoint: /V1/products/{sku}

Response: {
"message": "Consumer is not authorized to access %resources",
"parameters": {
    "resources": "Magento_Catalog::products"
}}
```

As admin, I can access these resources. But I need to access these resources as a customer.

I am using community edition of Magento 2.3.

I need to ask how can I grant access to customer and guest user of these resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default User type **`Customer`** has [Accessible resources](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication.html#accessible-resources) (defined in **`webapi.xml`**) with **`anonymous`** or **`self permission`**.

The rest API endpoint **`/V1/products/{sku}`** has a resource ref of **`"Magento_Catalog::products"`** that's why customer has no access on it.
In order to access it using customer's token, you have to create a **`custom endpoint`** that will extend a specific API endpoint with `<resource ref="self"/>`
Check below example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/products/product:sku" method="GET">
      <service class="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" method="get"/>
      <resources>
         <resource ref="sef" />
      </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

And you can use the custom endpoint **`/V1/products/product/{sku}`** to get details of the specific product using **`customer's token.`**